# Can I make a call from iPhone 5s via WiFi?

Tags: wifi, wifi-calling

I have an iPhone 5s that ATT will not unlock.  Can I make calls via WiFi if the SIM card is still in it but I have no cell carrier? Phone is at IOS 8.1.3.

Comment: not enough to be an answer, as you might live anywhere in the world… but Virgin [UK] have an app for that. Dial from anywhere you can use wifi & it uses your home phone 'connection' rather than charging your 'mobile provider'

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 VoIP apps that are widely used here in Southeast Asia.

http://www.viber.com/en/#iphone

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id414478124?mt=8&ls=1

Check them out.

Answer (score 1):

FaceTime Audio works great, but only Apple product to Apple Product (iPhone to Mac or iPad to iPhone, etc.) I'd give it a try, just go to the FaceTime app and tap Audio on the top, then select or add who you wish to contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you will need a VOIP application for that.

Something like [Skype](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skype-for-iphone/id304878510?mt=8) works well over WiFi, since you can actually call phones (landlines or Cellular).

The Skype app is free, however calling phones is charged (but much less than AT&T was)

As you know the only limitation is you have to be in a WiFi signal range.

Comment: Not sure why someone marked you down. +1 from me. I was going to add TalkaTone and Google hangouts to the list. All work great.